# TikZ: Create a downward chain of nodes with different heights

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to create a downward chain of TikZ nodes. Some nodes are rotated and they may differ in height.

Consider the output of the MWE below:

[image]

The horizontal chain adapts to the different widths of the nodes, while the downward one doesn't. Might this have anything to do with the rotation? Do you know how I can get the downward chain to prevent intersections of node like the horizontal does?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes}
\tikzstyle{arrow}
  = [ shape=single arrow
    , single arrow head extend=.75em
    , single arrow head indent=.25em
    , minimum width=3em
    , draw
    ]
\tikzstyle{rarrow}
  = [ shape=single arrow
    , single arrow head extend=.75em
    , single arrow head indent=.25em
    , minimum width=3em
    , draw
    , rotate=-90
    ]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,every node/.style={on chain,join}]
        \node[arrow] {foo};
        \node[arrow] {foo};
        \node[arrow] {foooooooooo};
        \node[arrow] {foo};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going below,every node/.style={on chain,join}]
        \node[rarrow] {foo};
        \node[rarrow] {foo};
        \node[rarrow] {foooooooooo};
        \node[rarrow] {foo};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite fast workaround as the `tikzpicture` environments are independent of each other:

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes}
\tikzstyle{arrow}
  = [ shape=single arrow
    , single arrow head extend=.75em
    , single arrow head indent=.25em
    , minimum width=3em
    , draw
    ]
\tikzstyle{rarrow}
  = [ shape=single arrow
    , single arrow head extend=.75em
    , single arrow head indent=.25em
    , minimum width=3em
    , draw
    ]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,every node/.style={on chain,join}]
        \node[arrow] {foo};
        \node[arrow] {foo};
        \node[arrow] {foooooooooo};
        \node[arrow] {foo};
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
\rotatebox{-90}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,
 every node/.style={on chain,join}]
        \node[rarrow] {foo};
        \node[rarrow] {foo};
        \node[rarrow] {foooooooooo};
        \node[rarrow] {foo};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]